# Custom tray icon notification balloon

Tags: c#, winforms, system-tray, trayicon

I have a C# program that sits in the system tray and pops up a notification balloon now and then. I'd like to provide 2-3 buttons *on the notification balloon* to allow the user to take various actions when the notification appears - rather than, for example, having to click the notification balloon to display a form containing buttons for each possible action.

I'm looking for suggestions on the best way to go about implementing this.

Edit: clarification, I want to provide buttons on the notification balloon so the user can take direct action on the notification rather than having to take action through some other part of the application (a form or menu for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in method for this.  I would suggest writing your own "balloon" and activating that instead of calling .ShowBalloon()

Comment: Accepted. I thought it might be quite easy to add buttons to a notification balloon but it seems it might be much easier to just create a custom notification balloon. Thanks :-)

Comment: yeah, sure would be nice to have it built in.  mebe Windows 3147 will include it :)

Answer (score -1):

This is how I do it. It may not be the correct way of doing it. I do this way because `.ShowBalloonTip(i)` doesn't work as expected for me. It doesn't stay for `i` seconds and go off. So I do in another thread and forcefully dispose off.

```
    private static NotifyIcon _notifyIcon;

    //you can call this public function
    internal static void ShowBalloonTip(Icon icon)
    {
        BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
        worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
        worker.RunWorkerAsync(icon);
    }

    private static void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Show(e);
        Thread.Sleep(2000); //meaning it displays for 2 seconds
        DisposeOff();
    }

    private static void Show(DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        _notifyIcon = new NotifyIcon();
        _notifyIcon.Icon = (Icon)e.Argument;

         _notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Environment file is opened";
        _notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = "Press alt+tab to switch between environment files";

        _notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
        _notifyIcon.Visible = true;
        _notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000); //sadly doesnt work for me :(
    }

    private static void DisposeOff()
    {
        if (_notifyIcon == null)
            return;

        _notifyIcon.Dispose();
        _notifyIcon = null;
    }
```

Comment: "It doesn't stay for i seconds and go off." -- it isn't supposed to. It's supposed to disappear i milliseconds after the user's next activity, where i has a system-specific minimum. The idea is that if you're presenting a notification the user should see, you should give the user a chance to actually see it. What if he's out for a drink? And if you say that it then does not matter that he doesn't see the notification, you shouldn't have shown the notification in the first place, that's not what they're for.

Comment: @hvd thats new to me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Apologies I wasn't quite clear enough with my post and have updated it - I'm able to display the notification balloon but I want to allow users to take one of several possible actions directly through the balloon rather than having to click through to a form or menu to take action (i.e. by placing buttons directly on the notification balloon).